# add autocomplete to textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, autocomplete

I've created a code for autocompletion, but dont know why it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub btnrefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnrefresh.Click
    txtledgersearch.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    txtledgersearch.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    Dim DataCollection As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
    getData(DataCollection)
    txtledgersearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource = DataCollection

End Sub
Private Sub getData(ByVal dataCollection As AutoCompleteStringCollection)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
    con = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    con.Open()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    sqlstr = "SELECT LedgerTab.lname FROM LedgerTab;"

    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlstr, con)
    For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
        dataCollection.Add(row(0).ToString())
    Next

End Sub
```

I'm not getting why my code is not working.

Comment: Did you get some errors? Have you debugged your code?

Comment: not getting any error

Comment: have you run debugging?

Comment: hey man ... please give some more input ... when you debugg it you should see whats stored in the vars and whats going on with code ...

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` and run your program.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether data is filled to dataCollection from DB.
try moving this scode snipet to load event

```
txtledgersearch.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
txtledgersearch.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
Dim DataCollection As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
getData(DataCollection)
txtledgersearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource = DataCollection
```